# What happens if I modify the slice I'm ranging over?

Tags: go

I recently noticed that I had done this:

```
for t, ts := range timespans {
    // remove current item
    if t+1 < len(timespans) {
        timespans = append(timespans[:t], timespans[t+1:]...)
    } else {
        timespans = timespans[:t]
    }
```

where

```
var timespans []TimeSpan
```

and

```
type TimeSpan [2]time.Time
```

How does `range`'s work internally?

Does it work like a `for i:=0; i<42; i++` loop (and skip items) or does it range over a copy of `timespans`, as it looked when the loop first started, or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer in the language specification.

> The range expression is evaluated once before beginning the loop[...]`

So it operates on a copy. Awesome!

Answer (score 2):

It works on a copy of the slice, you can modify the slice's data in place but it will ignore append and such.